# Invoke executeCommand with 'Add all missing imports' in VSCode Extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm writing a VSCode extension that does some code manipulation and eventually I'd like to run the command that 'Add all missing imports' in 'Show Fixes' (the lightbulb) on that specific problem.

Any idea how can I invoke this command?

I've tried to invoke: `vscode.commands.executeCommand('problems.action.showQuickFixes');`
but I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFocusElement' of null`
Even when focusing on the code I'm trying to fix

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by calling the following command `_typescript.applyFixAllCodeAction` with arguments: [document.fileName, { fixId: 'fixMissingImport'}]

Comment: is that command still available? Seems to be removed